# how can i get a url that is in data-href attribute of <a> using BeautifulSoup in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


result = requests.get("https://www.google.co.in/searchq=ntest&oq=ntest&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j35i39l2j0l2.4898j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
page = result.text
doc = soup(page,"html5lib")

a = doc.find_all('h3',{'class':'r'})

for i in a:
    b = i.a
    print(b.get('data-href'))
```

I don't know why it is unable to access the data-href attribute of anchor tag.

Comment: Your link might be dead; I get a 404 error.

Comment: You need `for tag in soup.find_all('a'): print(tag['data-href'])`

Comment: ...and insert a `?` parameter into the `url`: `https://www.google.co.in/search?q=...`...